# Custom SpanAdjuster is not working in Sleuth 1.3.X

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth, distributed-tracing

I'm using Sleuth 1.3.X to add distributed tracing feature to a microservice, I'm trying to change the Span name, and I came across this [Link](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/1.3.x/multi/multi__customizations.html#_customization_of_reported_spans)

It says that the SpanReporter should inject the SpanAdjuster and allow span manipulation before the actual reporting is done.

How I can do that?

here is my SpanAdjuster

```
@Bean
SpanAdjuster mySpanAdjuster(){
    return (SpanAdjuster) span -> {
        if ("/rest/XYZ/message".equals(span.tags().get("http.path"))){
             Span.builder().from(span).name("Rest API").build();
        }
        return span;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be doing this as the docs suggests, check out the Sleuth auto-configuration, it should be injected, it might happen that you are using an incompatible version of another module/project, e.g.: Spring Boot.

Also, we are about to release Sleuth 3.1.0, you are two major versions behind, this version is not supported anymore, so even if this is a bug, there won't be a new release from the 1.x line that could fix this.